# discord.py bot not joining channel

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

ok so here is my code

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN = 'THIS_IS_MY_BOT_TOKEN'

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # we do not want the bot to reply to itself
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    #typing cat
    if message.content.startswith('!cat'):
        msg = 'https://media.giphy.com/media/JIX9t2j0ZTN9S/giphy.gif'.format(message)
        await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)
    #I dont need sleep i need awnsers
    if message.content.startswith('!sleep'):
        msg = 'https://i.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/original/000/030/338/New.jpg'.format(message)
        await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)
    #murica
    if message.content.startswith('!murica'):
        msg = 'https://www.dictionary.com/e/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Murica_1000x700.jpg'.format(message)
        await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)
    if message.content.startswith('!why'):
        msg = 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rb132Y785zUjj2RP2G-a_yXBcNK5Ut9z/view?usp=sharing'.format(message)
        await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def join(ctx):
    if ctx.message.author.voice:
        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
        await channel.connect()

client.run(TOKEN)
```

the bot joins the sever, but when I say .join, nothing happens

the voice channel I want to join is called `Club Meeting` if that helps

Not entirely sure why, I have no errors when I run it. Anyone have any idea whats going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is your lack of [Bot.process_commands](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.process_commands) You need to put that at the end of your on_message function. That seems to be the reason your command isn't working.

From The Docs:

**Why does on_message make my commands stop working?**
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working

Comment: the on_message if for emotes and is not related to the problem im having. what im trying to do is get the bot to join a voice channel.

Comment: You said the bot is in the server but when you execute the command nothing happens.  Like I said in my comment you need to use Bot.process_commands or else your on_message function will make your commands not work. I linked you to the FAQ if you read it you would know. Try it. Make another command that prints something and see if that works.